# Lua: getting rid of part of a path (sub, gsub,gmatch?)

Tags: lua, scripting

So i have this variable:

```
a = [[C:\aaa\aaa\aa\bbb\ccc\ddd]]
```

And i need to end up here:

```
a = [[ccc\ddd]]
```

Note that the path (the aaa,ccc and ddd folders) might be different from time to time, but the word "bbb" is always gonna be there and thats what i´d like to use to start chopping the text (from the end of the word not from the beginning)

I´ve been reading some string tutorials and everything i tried just doesnt work (pretty new to scripting here). I think the "\" character messes things up.

Whats the best way to deal with this? Thaaaanks!

Comment: `a:match[[\(bbb\.*)]]`

Answer (score 1):

This is a good time to make use of patterns.

Information on that here: [understanding lua patterns](https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns)

With a pattern you could use `string.match` to flexibly capture the part of the string you want

```
a ="C:\\aaa\\aaa\\aa\\bbb\\ccc\\ddd"
print(string.match(a, "bbb\\(.*)"))
```

Comment: Sorry i realized i made the wrong question. What i want to have is ccc\ddd, which can be variable, but have bbb as the chopping point. I am editing my first post...damn